# Replicating Symantec Endpoints "Access Denied" security?

Tags: c#, c++, security, access-denied, symantec

I'm sure many of you have experienced Symantec Endpoint and its ability to prevent users from killing its processes resulting in an "Access Denied" to the user even when the kill is performed via the local Administrator or System user.

Id like to figure out how to introduce something similar in my own code.

Does anyone have any experience with this and can point me in the correct direction.

My preference is C# but I expect something like this to be at a lower level C++.

Comment: C# using `unsafe` code blocks can deal with pointers, `stackalloc`, etc, etc

Comment: I typed `win32 Access Denied prevent killing process` into Google and found [this](http://csharptest.net/1043/how-to-prevent-users-from-killing-your-service-process/)

Comment: @ta.speot.is Thanks ill have a look.